# Cargo shows an error compiling "qml v0.0.9"

Tags: qt, rust, qml, rust-cargo

I tried to compile [a sample Rust program](https://www.vandenoever.info/blog/2017/02/17/a-simple-rust-gui-with-qml.html) which uses QML and got the following error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `qml v0.0.9`
process didn't exit successfully: `/home/olaf/SourceCode/rust_projects/sousa/target/debug/build/qml-cf7d687f9f68bd13/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot build qrc resource:
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++    
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version \"1.8.11\") 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also \"/home/olaf/SourceCode/rust_projects/sousa/target/debug/build/qml-29ff7d8391813cc4/out/DOtherSide/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log\"."
"Klone nach \'DOtherSide\' ...
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:27 (message):
  The imported target \"Qt5::Core\" references the file

     \"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.5.1\"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     \"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake\"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:43 (_qt5_Core_check_file_exists)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:134 (_populate_Core_target_properties)
  lib/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)

"', /home/olaf/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/qml-0.0.9/build.rs:32:8
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Edit:
I have installed Qt 5.8, 5.9.1 and 5.9.3 but they are installed at my home folder ~/Qt and I think Cargo is looking somewhere else /usr/lib/...
How do I tell Cargo where to look for Qt?
Or do I have to install a specific package of Qt under /usr/lib/...?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error, the issue is that the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`**`libQt5Core.so`**`.5.5.1` (which a Qt dynamic library) does not exist, which means that you need to install this version of Qt on your machine.

If you're on Ubuntu or an Ubuntu-derived distro, you can follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu#Installation_Guide) to install it.

Comment: Thx...I have altered my question. I have a couple of libQt5Core.so installed but not at the right location.

Comment: Is there also an install routine to install Qt runtime only under /usr/lib/x86...?